SCAD shifting a slot to the center of frame

In the image above, you can see a rectangular frame and a small slot off to the side on one side. I want to get that slot in the center of that side, but my code is not doing that.
This is the code I have for the slot:
// Create the top cutout for the headband in the middle of the shorter side
        translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, -outer_width / 2, -border_height]) {
            cube([slot_width, border_height + 1, slot_depth]);
        }
    }

In my mind, if I /2 that should do it, but not sure what is going on. Any ideas?
I tried switching the outer_length with Outer_width, and adding a 0 in front, but hasn't worked.
Here is the code for the whole frame, including code for the slot:
// Parameters for the rectangular frame
outer_length = 85;       // Outer length of the frame (in mm)
outer_width = 65;        // Outer width of the frame (in mm)
border_thickness = 2;    // Thickness of the raised border (in mm)
border_height = 10;      // Height of the raised border (in mm)
inner_length = outer_length - 2 * border_thickness;  // Inner length of the frame (in mm)
inner_width = outer_width - 2 * border_thickness;    // Inner width of the frame (in mm)
bottom_thickness = 1;    // Thickness of the thin opaque bottom layer (in mm)
corner_radius = 5;       // Radius for rounded corners (in mm)
slot_width = 10;         // Width for headband slots (in mm)
slot_depth = 5;          // Depth for headband slots (in mm)

// Function to create a rectangular frame with rounded corners, a hollow interior, and a thin opaque bottom layer
module rec_frame() {
    difference() {
        // Create the outer shell with rounded corners and raised border
        translate([0, 0, -border_height])
        linear_extrude(height = border_height + bottom_thickness) {
            offset(r = corner_radius) {
                square([outer_length, outer_width], center = true);
            }
        }

        // Create the inner hollow part with rounded corners
        translate([0, 0, -border_height])
        linear_extrude(height = border_height + bottom_thickness) {
            offset(r = corner_radius - 1) {
                square([inner_length, inner_width], center = true);
            }
        }

        // Create the thin opaque bottom layer
        translate([0, 0, -bottom_thickness])
        square([outer_length, outer_width], center = true);
        
        // Create the top cutout for the headband in the middle of the shorter side
        translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, -outer_width / 2, -border_height]) {
            cube([slot_width, border_height + 1, slot_depth]);
        }
    }

    // Create the thin opaque bottom layer
    translate([0, 0, -bottom_thickness - border_height])
    linear_extrude(height = bottom_thickness) {
        offset(r = corner_radius) {
            square([outer_length, outer_width], center = true);
        }
    }
}

// Create the frame using the module
rec_frame();

For the second slot that is indented
        // Create the indent for the headband in the center of the frame
        translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, 0, -border_height - indent_depth]) {
            cube([slot_width, outer_width, indent_depth]);
        }

        // Create the top slot in the indent for the headband
        translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, 0, -border_height - indent_depth]) {
            cube([slot_width, outer_width, slot_depth]);
        }

        // Create the bottom slot in the indent for the headband
        translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, 0, -border_height - indent_depth - slot_depth]) {
            cube([slot_width, outer_width, slot_depth]);
        }
    }```


Please provide a [mre].

Impossible to say without seeing the code for the base object and the values of the variables.

"I want to get that slot in the center of that side, but my code is not doing that." Which center? Centered up/down? Or left/right? Or both?

Thanks for the response! I've edited the post to include the code for the frame!

The vertical position is correct, I just want it to be in the center of the shorter side.

The cube that you're cutting out for the slot hole cube is created without center = true, so it's edge-aligned along the Y axis. To center it on the Y axis, all you have do is move it half its own width in the negative Y direction.
In the translate, change the Y parameter from - outer_width / 2 to - slot_width / 2:
translate([outer_length / 2 - slot_width / 2, - slot_width / 2, -border_height]) {
    cube([slot_width, border_height + 1, slot_depth]);
}



Oh my gosh thank you!! Wow so helpful.

I have another question but it's trickier and no worries if you don't answer but thought I'd ask as it may be easy for you!! I am trying to add another slot in the middle of the frame, basically for a headband to slide into (a second time). So the headband would slide into the first slot (pictured) and then again through a slot (indented) in the middle. Here is what I have

I added to original as it isn't formatting as code in the comments

Use
%cube([slot_width, border_height + 1, slot_depth]);

That will make the cube visible.
Translate it up about 10 on the z axis.
Then fiddle with your other translate, and you will able to see what effect
the translate has on the cube.
Move it where you need it.
Remove the translate +10.
Remove the %.
You should be good to go.
